# How to set default date value as current date in a datepicker textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepicker. 
I wanted to set today's date as default in one datepicker, and 7 day before in another datepicker. Also I want drop-down list for selecting month and year in datepicker.

in script I wrote the code below

```
 $("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', 
                 changeMonth: true,
                 changeYear: true,
                 yearRange: '-70:+10',


});

$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', 
                 changeMonth: true,
                 changeYear: true,
                 yearRange: '-70:+10',


});
```

but it is not working for me.
please help me to solve this.

i also tried  `setDate, new Date()`

Comment: Is it showing any error in console?

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle? It will be better to provide you the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work for you,try it :

```js
var lastDate = new Date();
lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate() - 7);//any date you want
$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker('setDate', lastDate);
```

Comment: thank for your code. it works for me. I have another issue can u help me to solve it?

Comment: Changeyear and changeMonth are not working for me. Do u know how can i solve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f2md3zy5/225/        check this. i wanted to get it like this. but when i am using the same code in my website i don't get the drop-down for month and year.

Comment: which jquery /.js scripts are you using?, use latest ones. That might be the reason why you are not getting the entire functionality.

Comment: use    jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: i am using jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  use these may help you

Comment: sorry something went wrong then, I didn't find any problem in there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ?

```
 var currentDate = new Date();
 $("#datepickerTo").datepicker({ defaultDate:  currentDate});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLastWeek(_date){
    var today = new Date(_date);
    var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
    return lastWeek ;
}

var lastWeekDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy', getLastWeek('20/11/2015'));
 $("#dateTimePicker").datepicker( "setDate" , laswWeekDate );
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late, but here are some one liners I wrote.

**jQuery**

```js
$('#date').val(new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10));
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```js
document.getElementById("date_expired").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting value for both datepicker after you have bind datepicker to them.
i.e after you above code. try below code.

```
$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker("setDate" , new Date());
```

for next datepicker

```
$("#datepickerTo").datepicker("setDate" , "selected date of datepickerFrom - 7");
```

Check this Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2md3zy5/221/

Comment: thank u for your code . I got values in textbox. but i need a date that is one week before current date. now i am getting value that is one week after current date.

Comment: ok. You have to modify the last line. to decrease the 7 days 
$("#datepickerTo").datepicker("setDate" , "selected date of datepickerFrom - 7");
to 
with the solution from @AkhilN

Comment: i have another issue. Changeyear and changeMonth are not working for me. Do u know how can i solve this?

Comment: i got answer in fiddle but i don't get answer in my webpage.

Comment: In that case there must be some confliction in your webpage.
is it live ? if yes share that url. 
else create an html and share it.

Comment: sorry i don't have permission to share that.

Comment: Check in your code, do you have any other jquery plugin which has similar features ?

Comment: then its should work. What exactly you are getting when the script is fully loaded? No dropdowns for the year/month? 
Can you check by clearing the browser & application cache ?

Comment: i don't get drop-down for year and month. i cleared browsing & application cache,but still the problem is there

Comment: get the latest jquery.ui and set it in your project and chek

Comment: in page inspect i got drop-down for month and year. but when i try to run the website it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
$('.dateField').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
I mean to say you can use minDate or maxdate

```
                    jQuery("#datePickerTo").datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: datePickerRange,
                        maxDate: new Date
                    });
```